# Netbeans: Try to load file but not found (Java)

Tags: java, netbeans

I have every time the same problem when I'm trying to load files with Java in Netbeans (6.9).
It seems that the files aren't found. I get the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

In this context:

```
File file = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.xml").getFile());
// or this also don't work
File file = new File("file.xml");
```

The file `file.xml` is in the same directory as the `Main.java` file.
How could I load this file?

Comment: My guess is you need to move the `file.xml` to the top level directory of your netbeans project.

Comment: Usually we put the xml resource files in the root directory of the project for Netbeans to find them.

Comment: I tried that also but with the same error.

Comment: At the moment it looks like that: http://i.imgur.com/vjFjl.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work (it does for me):

```
String path = URLDecoder.decode(getClass().getResource("file.xml").getFile(), "UTF-8");
File f = new File(path);
```

If I understand the Javadocs correctly, this should be the same as using `getClass().getClassloader().getResource()` but in my experience it is different

Comment: getResource() must contain a parameter (String).

Comment: Okay, this returns the right path to the file but there is an error at the path: The path contains a whitespace so there's a `%20` inside the path which Java says there is no such file but there is one!?

Comment: You need to use URLDecoder in get the "real" filename. I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you add a line so it says something along the lines (untested):

```
File f = new File(....);
System.out.println("f=" + f.getAbsolutePath());
// do stuff with f
```

This will tell you exactly where the file is expected to be and allow you to figure out what exactly is going on.

Comment: It returns the root folder of the whole project (inside are folders like build or src or dist etc.).

Comment: If I set `build\\classes\\project\\file.xml` as path it works?!

Comment: Thats because the default "current working directory" for a new launch configuration is the root of the project.  Try again, with the getResource() approach.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you might need to add an extra `/` in front

```
File file = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/file.xml").getFile());
```

Comment: Why would the / be Windows specific?

Comment: That says it is to be found in the _root_ of the classpath instead of relative to the original resource.

Comment: Strange, I could have sworn there was a comment stating that the / will make this Windows *specific* (Something, like "don't do that, it'll make it work on Windows only).