# Netbeans Built .jar doesn't work with class file inside

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

[I had problems while finding the path of file(s) in Netbeans.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433785/netbeans-try-to-load-file-but-not-found-java).

Problem is already solved (checked answer).

Today I noticed another problem: When project is finished,
I have to execute the generated .jar to launch the program, but it doesn't work because an error occurs: NullPointer (where to load a file) when accessing/openning jar outside Netbeans.

Is it possible to open a file with the class file in Java/Netbeans which works in Netbeans and even in any directory?

I've found already some threads about my problem in site but none was helpful.

Code:

```
File file = new File(URLDecoder.decode(this.getClass().getResource("file.xml").getFile(), "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that File only refer to files on the filesystem, not files in jars.

If you want a more generic locator, use a URL which is what getResource provides.  However, usually you don't need to know the location of the file, you just need its contents, in which case you can use getResourceAsInputStream()

This all assumes your class path is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to load a file anywhere on your file system that the java process has access to. You just need to have the path explicitly set in your getResource call.

For example:

```
File file = new File(URLDecoder.decode(this.getClass().getResource("C:\\foo\\bar\\file.xml").getFile(), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: How could I set the absolute path directly? I have to get this work on other systems too so this isn't the/a solution for me.

Comment: Isn't it the same as File file = new File("C:\\foo\\bar\\file.xml");